# How to hide an item in the ScrollView when it is visible on the screen?

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, geometryreader

I'm trying to hide `BottomRoundedRectangle()` when I see the 2nd `LazyVStack {…}` on the screen, but it doesn't work.

`value` in `.onPreferenceChange(OffsetKey.self)` doesn't change as well.

```swift
struct OffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat

    static let defaultValue: Value = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct OffsetKeyBackground: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            content
                .preference(
                    key: OffsetKey.self,
                    value: -reader.frame(in: .named("secondLazyStack")).origin.y
                )
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollQuestion: View {
    @State
    private var elementValue: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            // Dynamic long text there
            LazyVStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
                    .frame(height: 920) // dynamic text, 920 for example, may be bigger
            }
            
            // 2nd LazyVStack
            LazyVStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .frame(height: 820)
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "secondLazyStack")
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            // How to hide this correctly when we see second LazyVStack ?
            BottomRoundedRectangle()
//          .opacity(elementValue < 50 ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .modifier(OffsetKeyBackground())
        .onPreferenceChange(OffsetKey.self) { value in
            debugPrint(value)
            
            elementValue = value
        }
    }
}

struct BottomRoundedRectangle: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .frame(height: 40)
                .foregroundStyle(.indigo)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
            Text("Visible only in first LazyVStack")
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ScrollQuestion()
}
```

What do I need to do to hide `BottomRoundedRectangle()` correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect this by wrapping the second `LazyVStack` in a `GeometryReader`.

If the scroll view's frame intersects the frame of the `LazyVStack`, that means at least some part of the `LazyVStack` is on screen.

```
struct IsOnScreenKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static let defaultValue = false
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct DetectIsOnScreen: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            content
                .preference(
                    key: IsOnScreenKey.self,
                    // bounds(of: .scrollView) gives us the scroll view's frame
                    // frame(in: .local) gives us the LazyVStack's frame
                    // both are in the local coordinate space
                    value: reader.bounds(of: .scrollView)?.intersects(reader.frame(in: .local)) ?? false
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
@State
private var isSecondVStackVisible = false

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        LazyVStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
                .frame(height: 920)
        }
        LazyVStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .modifier(DetectIsOnScreen())
                .frame(height: 820)
                .onPreferenceChange(IsOnScreenKey.self) { value in
                    isSecondVStackVisible = value
                }
        }
    }
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
        BottomRoundedRectangle()
                  .opacity(isSecondVStackVisible ? 0 : 1)
    }
}
```

Note that in this particular case, it is also possible to just set the preference to

```
reader.bounds(of: .scrollView) != nil
```

This is because `LazyVStack`s are lazy - if they are not on screen, it literally doesn't exist. The geometry reader can't convert the scroll view's frame to a coordinate space that doesn't exist.

Comment: Great solution! But it doesn't work at simulator and physical device 
iOS 17 in both cases.
@Sweeper Which iOS version did you test the code on ?

Comment: @NickRossik iOS 17.0 Simulator, Xcode 15.0. How exactly did it "not work"?

Comment: BottomRoundedRectangle() still visible when I see 2nd LazyVStack.

.onPreferenceChange doesn't change the value, isSecondVStackVisible always false

Comment: @NickRossik I cannot reproduce that. The full code is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Sweeper777/2c0c38dfda703317a9bb6fa45daa8300). Did you make any copy-paste mistakes or did I forget to mention some other changes I did?

Comment: double-checked six times + copy-paste gist and still wrong behaviour but I 100% sure this code correct, hell

Comment: @NickRossik I was actually able to reproduce it on previews, and I was able to fix it by moving `onPreferenceChange` to be on the second `LazyVStack` (or even the `RoundedRectangle`) instead. Not sure if my code is wrong or this is a SwiftUI bug.

Comment: Aha, I see what's going on!
Either it's a bug or it's the sequence of modifiers.
Anyway, applying the .onPreferenceChange modifier in `RoundedRectangle` or 2nd `LazyVStack`, it works!

Thanks for taking the time and helping me out.